# How to add a column of indices of a character in a string on a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have a spark dataframe with a binary string column. I want to add a column to a dataframe with indices of 1 in each element of the column.

I have a pattern matching function for getting indices but I need to apply this function to a spark dataframe column.

```
def patternMatching(pattern: String, str: String): List[Int] =
  pattern.r.findAllMatchIn(str).map(_.start).toList


patternMatching("1", "000110010010001110")
```

Eventually, what I'm trying to do is getting the dataframe below;

```
Binary_String   |   Vec
         1010   |   List(1,3)
         1100   |   List(1,2)
         0010   |   List(3)
         0000   |   List()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a UDF:

```
val patternMatching = udf((pattern: String, str: String) => 
    pattern.r.findAllMatchIn(str).map(_.start).toList)
```

Apply it to a column:

```
Seq("000110010010001110").toDF("x")
    .select(patternMatching(lit("0"),col("x")).as("x"))
    .show()
```